# Correct syntax for importing bot types and values in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-types

Here is valid TypeScript, but TypeScript-ESLint will yelp about duplicate imports:

```
import type { ExampleType } from "@Alias/OtherModule";
import { ExampleValue } from "@Alias/OtherModule";
```

Some there some valid syntax like below?

```
import { ExampleValue }, type { ExampleType } from "@Alias/OtherModule";
```

By the way: maybe I don't need to split imports to type and values if types are being used inside project only?

Comment: I don't think that's possible.

Comment: @cherryblossom, if so, next step is issue in TypeScript-eslint.

Comment: Hi, if you're still interested in a lint rule that reports duplicate imports, you can use [`eslint-plugin-import`'s `no-duplicates` rule](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/no-duplicates.md), which works for type imports in TS.